# question regarding inequalities and equivalence

Tags: inequality

if you have a question where you let x,y>0 and want to prove if $x^2<y^2$ then $x<y$ then would it be correct to use $\iff$ as you go through so

$x^2<y^2$ $\iff$ $x^2-y^2<0$ $\iff$ $(x+y)(x-y)<0$ $\iff$ $x<y$

Im mainly asking about if the last one is correct i believe it is because you are under the assumption that x and y are both positive.

Thanks

Comment: It is true under the assumption that $x+y>0$, so they need not be both positive.

Comment: Oh yeah thanks.